# Programming a load balancer with sockets using C

Tags: c, http, sockets, web

I'm trying to make a load balancer for 3 HTTP servers{hosts= "web1", "web2", "web3"}{load balancer ports="8081","8082","8083"}.

This load balancer transfers HTTP requests randomly to one of the servers and then returns the result of the request to the sender.

I'm begining with sockets so if any one could tell me what would the program look like?

If it is not clear I'm ready to give more details.

Comment: First detail we need is what you have tried?

Comment: Nothing, I really have no idea, for the moment i'm learning how to create a basic client/server application using sockets. And I really need a program for the load balancer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags stand alone.  That is, combining `web` and `server` does not mean you're talking about web servers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out if the requests are stateful, meaning - the requests belong to a valid session, then such  requests should be consistently routed to the same server to avoid failures and inconsistencies. Fresh requests can be routed to any of the servers based on load balancing algorithm eg. round robin or least loaded server etc.